# NSIS inetc multiple file cancel

Tags: download, nsis

I'm using the INETC plugin for NSIS to download multiple files (50+)

Everything seems to be working fine except for one little annoyance at this point

When you get to the part where the files are being downloaded, you are unable to abort the installer.

The 'X' at the top right hand of the Installer (windows close) is greyed out. The INETC plugin itself has a 'cancel' button, but this only cancels the download of the current file, causing the installation package to resume to the next.. With +50 files in queue, this is an annoyance and the only way to get around it is to End Task the process

To call `INETC::get` i have created a function called `DownloadFile` which does some validations and takes a filename as an argument

I then call it in the following manner

```
Strcpy $BatchFile "filename.fileextension"
Call DownloadFile
```

Essentially, i'd like to know how I can use INETC to download multiple files while not preventing the user from being able to abort the installation entirely

## EDIT: DownloadFile code

```
Function DownloadFile

 IfFileExists "$EXEDIR\$Targetfolder\$BatchFile" +1
 md5dll::GetMD5File "$EXEDIR\$Targetfolder\$BatchFile"
 Pop $0
 Strcpy $MD5file $0

 push "$EXEDIR\$Targetfolder\$BatchFile"
 Push "\"
 Call GetAfterChar
 Pop $R0
 Strcpy $Filename $R0

 push $Filename
 call GetBaseName
 Pop $2
 Strcpy $NoEXTFile $2

 ${If} $NoEXTFILE != $MD5file
   SetDetailsView show
   Detailprint "File $Batchfile doesnt exit or MD5 is faulty. Re-downloading"
   inetc::get /RESUME "Do you want to retry?" "[url]/$BatchFile" "$EXEDIR\$Targetfolder\$BatchFile"
 ${Else}
   Detailprint "File $BatchFile exists, MD5 is good"
 ${EndIf}

 sleep 2000

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Beware that `IfFileExists "$EXEDIR\$Targetfolder\$BatchFile" +1` will not do what you expect. Syntax is `IfFileExists file jump_if_present [jump_if_not]`: if present, it will jump to `+1` = next statement, and as you do not specify a `jump_if_not` label or offset it will do nothing else than going to next statement if it does not exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call inetc::get in a loop, once for each file. If the return value you popped off the stack is not "OK" then abort the loop.

Comment: Anders, thanks for the suggestion.. Would you happen to have an example? Not sure i'm understanding the logic

Comment: You should call INetC as `INetC::get "http://..." "$path\name.ext" /END` and then do `Pop $0`. You can then check if $0 is "OK", if not, don't download the next file...